Unsupported analytics SDK version
While trying to access videos on the CTV News site, I often can not watch the videos as the following error message occrus:


Unsupported analytics SDK version, please provide the expected SDK
7.8.0+2310050509 of comScore prior to the video player instantiation.

Is there something that can be done on the user end to rectify this issue, or is it a problem with the host? I have tried using different browsers but get the same result; no video.
Running:
Chrome Version 129.0.6668.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Windows 10 Pro

Apparently, the CTV News website is using an outdated version of the comScore analytics SDK, preventing the video player from working correctly.
You may try any of these solutions. Maybe one works maybe none:

Clear Browser Cache
Update Your Browser
Disable Extensions
Try Incognito Mode

If none works, contact their support.

Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain how you were able to surmise that the CTV website is using "outdated version of the comScore analytics SDK" ?

@KalamalkaKid, The message explicitly mentions "Unsupported analytics SDK version" and specifies the expected version as "7.8.0+2310050509." This suggests that the version currently in use on the CTV site is lower than this required version.
